# Implicits not found when declared in an object or trait

Tags: scala

I wrote this slick code and it works as expected

```
object TestApp extends App {
   implicit val getFooResult = GetResult(r => Foo(r.<<, r.<<))
   val query = sql"select a, b from foo".as[Foo]
}
case class Foo(a: Long, b: String)
```

This compiles and runs fine. but If I change the code to

```
object TestApp extends App with MyImplicits {
   val query = sql"select a, b from foo".as[Foo]
}
trait MyImplicits {
   implicit val getFooResult = GetResult(r => Foo(r.<<, r.<<))
}
case class Foo(a: Long, b: String)
```

Now I get a compile error

```
 could not find implicit value for parameter rconv: slick.jdbc.GetResult[Foo]
```

Same thing happens when I try

```
object TestApp extends App {
   import MyImplicits.getFooResult
   val query = sql"select a, b from foo".as[Foo]
}
object MyImplicits {
   implicit val getFooResult = GetResult(r => Foo(r.<<, r.<<))
}
case class Foo(a: Long, b: String)
```

It still gives the same error and does not see that the implicit is defined in the object.

Why am I loosing the visibility to the implicit when I move it in a trait or object?

Comment: The guideline is to not infer type of implicit; give it an explicit type. It breaks when the implicit is later in the source text. Maybe that's your problem.

Comment: spot on! thanks a lot!